# <doctype> VS <!DOCTYPE>

Tags: html, google-chrome, express

I'm using express to serve up HTML pages on Chrome, and external CSS does NOT work if I use:

```
< !DOCTYPE html >
```

but external CSS works for:

```
< doctype html >
```

Why is this?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please show us your code.

Comment: Because `<doctype html>` is a meaningless `HTMLUnknownElement`, rather than a `DocumentType`. You probably have really old, invalid HTML code.

Answer (score 5):

When you have `<!DOCTYPE html>` (as you probably have, you just wrote `< !DOCTYPE html >` here because you did not know how to use code markdown), it makes browsers work in “standards mode”. If you do not have it, or one of a few other longer constructs, browsers work in “[quirks mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html)”, which means that they apply dozens of quirks, meant to simulate bugs and oddities in very old versions of IE.

If you omit the exclamation mark, the string isn’t a magic thing that triggers “standards mode”. The construct `<DOCTYPE html>` or, equivalently,  `<doctype html>`, is just an undefined tag that gets ignored by browsers.

If the page now “works” in quirks mode, don’t mess things up. Keep the page as-is and change only what absolutely needs to be changed (such as content update). Changing it to work in standards mode would create much better possibilities for future development of the markup and styling of the page, but it may require a lot of work, maybe much more than complete redesign and rewrite (or just a little work; it would be difficult to estimate even if we saw the page and its code).

Comment: thanks Jukka, you were right I didn't know how to use the code markdown. Why would quirks mode allow my html page to pick up the external css reference?  

I can provide more information when I get home, but my site is very simple right now so I'd rather fix it now than later.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

If this one doesn't work => your page is **deprecated**. In this case you can:

- use `<doctype html>` or anything else (E.g.: nothing on that line) (workaround)

  - the browser tries to "downgrade" some features in order to work
- update your page until it will work according to the new conventions (solution)

`<!DOCTYPE>` performs some validations and if your page is too old, it won't work.